# Mule: apply filters and transformers according to HTTP method with REST router (and error handling)

Tags: rest, mule

I am struggling a little to satisfy my use-case with the Mule REST module. I'd like to have different transformations according to templateUri and HTTP method.

Here is my configuration:

```
    <flow name="http-interface">
        <http:inbound-endpoint address="http://localhost:8555" exchange-pattern="request-response"/>

        <rest:router templateUri="/schedule">
            <rest:post>
                <mxml:schema-validation-filter schemaLocations="xsd/scheduler.xsd" returnResult="true"/>
                <mxml:jaxb-xml-to-object-transformer jaxbContext-ref="jaxb-context"/>
                <vm:outbound-endpoint path="addjob"/>
            </rest:post>
        </rest:router>

        <choice-exception-strategy>
            <catch-exception-strategy when="exception.causedBy(org.mule.api.routing.filter.FilterUnacceptedException)">
                <logger level="ERROR" message="FilterUnacceptedException #[message]"/>
                <set-payload value="An error occurred while validating request. Please check the XML payload"/>
                <set-property propertyName="http.status" value="400"/>
            </catch-exception-strategy>
            <catch-exception-strategy when="exception.causedBy(java.lang.NullPointerException)">
                <logger level="ERROR" message="NullPointerException #[message]"/>
                <set-payload value="An error occurred while validating request. Please check the XML payload"/>
                <set-property propertyName="http.status" value="400"/>
            </catch-exception-strategy>
        </choice-exception-strategy>
    </flow>
```

When invalid XML is posted to the endpoint, I am getting a NullPointerException in NestedProcessorChain.processWithExtraProperties. Hence the nasty catch for this exception (not ideal).

My IDE gives schema validation errors both for rest:router in flow and the mxml filter/transformer in the rest:post element. I can remove the first by putting rest:router inside the inbound-endpoint. Results are the same, and most examples don't have this

I tried moving the filter/transformation to a separate flow on a VM endpoint. Validation is clean, but then I can't figure out how to get the HTTP error code and response back to the client.

Any help much appreciated,
Alfie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NPE is NestedProcessorChain.processWithExtraProperties is a bug in Mule REST Router, I raised an issue [here](https://github.com/mulesoft/mule-module-rest-router/issues/4), but it seems that REST Router is not supported anymore.

In general NPE is being thrown when you call your URI with HTTP method not described in your **<rest:router>** element. Expected exception is **UnsupportedHttpVerbException**. 
 
 
In details I have described the problem in one of my [blog posts](http://poznachowski.blogspot.co.uk/2013/10/exposing-restful-interface-with-mule-pt1.html), and provided fixed version of Mule REST Router.

Instead of using VM Endpoint, call the separate flow using **<flow-ref />** component or wrap it with [**<processor-chain />**](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Routing+Message+Processors#RoutingMessageProcessors-ProcessorChain).